# How can I post data to a phpMyAdmin database from Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm using Swift Playgrounds to create an app. I have a form that the user fills out.

```
Form {
      TextField("Email", text: $email)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
      SecureField("Password", text: $userpassword)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
      }
```

When the submit button is pressed, it calls a function. The function is successfully called, but inside it is what's causing me a problem.

I need to post the user's email and password to a phpMyAdmin database. I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried using the IP address and numerous other methods that I found online, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
func insertSignUpDataIntoDatabase(email: String, userpassword: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "")
    else{
        return
    }
    let body = "Email\(email)&Password\(userpassword)"
    let finalBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = finalBody
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){
        (data, response, error) in
        print(response as Any)
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else{
            return
        }
        print(data, String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "*unknown encoding*")
    }.resume()
}
```

Basically, I need to either:

**a) Take the email and password from the form that the user filled out and send it to a phpMyAdmin database directly from here**

OR

**b) Run a PHP script that I've already made with those two fields as variables**

Either method is completely fine, and guidance would be much appreciated. It would also be great if you guys could explain your answers because I'm new to Swift. Thanks!

**Edit:**

After doing some further research, I came to a resource that said this isn't possible. Would I need to use a database other than phpMyAdmin? If so, any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, so how would I run the PHP script directly from Swift Playgrounds with those two fields as variables? Is that possible, or would I have to use some other tool?

Comment: Looks like this is a client/server setup, your php part needs a REST api that can be accessed from swift using URLSession or similar. You have some research ahead of before this will run.

Comment: I have a database and a PHP script all set up, but how would I access it using URLSession?